# Haskell: Map function onto a list of lists

Tags: list, function, haskell, dictionary

How do you map a function to operate on lists within a list?
The following is just what I'm trying to do as an example, but I was just asking as a general question. Thanks in advance!

Right now, I'm trying to map a function, change, onto each lists of one list (returned by itrCol xs).

```
evalChange xs = map change $ itrCol xs
```

where itrCol returns a list of lists, where each containing list is a column.

```
itrCol xs = [getCol x xs | x <- (take (width xs) (iterate (\x -> (x + 1)*1) 0))]
```

getCol lists column given list of column indices

```
getCol :: Int -> [t] -> [t]
```

and change is:

```
change []     = []
change [x]    = [x]
change [x,y]  = [x,y]
change (x:y:z:ws) | x == y && y == z = 0 : y*(-1) : 0 : change ws
change (x:xs) =  x : change xs
```

Comment: Dont forget to accept an answer to your question =) (by clicking the green check icon on the answer)

Comment: Does the code you listed here give you any error messages? If so, what are they? If not, then what are you asking, exactly? The only error I see is that you used `width` when you might have meant `length`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could just use currying and another call to map.

```
map (map change) $ itrCol xs
```

To learn more about currying take a look at that [chapter in Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions), a great beginner book in Haskell.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm new to currying, but from my research, it is changing the number of arguments that a function takes?

Comment: The best explanation I've read is [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions). You really should read this whole book, wont find anything better!

Comment: Thank you! This is my first functional programming language, and it's quite different from the imperative languages I'm used to. I will definitely look into this!

Answer (score 15):

Check this out!

```
map           :: (a -> b) ->   [a]   ->   [b]
(map.map)     :: (a -> b) ->  [[a]]  ->  [[b]]
(map.map.map) :: (a -> b) -> [[[a]]] -> [[[b]]]
```

etc.

Comment: @AndrewC, yes, this isn't a pedagogically helpful answer and I probably wouldn't like it very much if I hadn't written it...

Answer (score 3):

`map` (and `fmap` more importantly) essentially lifts a function to work on lists, giving you a new function: (I added superfluous parens to make it more clear)

```
map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

If you map that second function `([a] -> [b])` you will get a function that works on lists of lists:

```
evalChange xs = map (map change) $ itrCol xs
```

(if this is not what you wanted then please clarify)

Comment: Thank you for your response! For some reason, this gives me an error. I tried to include the function type for map but it still gives me an error. I'm not sure how to copy that error in GHC onto here?

Comment: @user1670032 copy&paste it as an edit to your answer. If you don't know how then screenshot it.

Comment: @user1670032 If you are using ghci in Windows, you need to click on the icon at the top left corner then select "Edit -> Mark" from the menu. Now highlight what you want to copy and then push Enter. From there, just paste as usual wherever you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The type signature of `map` is:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

One sensible type signature for `change` is:

```
change :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
```

Now `map` expects a function from `a` to `b` as its first argument. If we give it `change`, a function from `[Integer]` to `[Integer]`, then `a = [Integer]` and `b = [Integer]`.

```
map change :: [[Integer]] -> [[Integer]]
```

Now if that list comprehension produced from `iterCol xs` supplies a `[[Integer]]`, then we can apply that to `map change`:

```
map change (itrCol xs) :: [[Integer]]
```

This all looks fine to me. It works because `map` is polymorphic. If you give it a function that turns A into B, then it will give you back a function that turns *lists of A* into *lists of B*. It doesn't matter what A and B are: as you can see here, they can even be lists themselves!